# Change the text of a paper-button with JavaScript (polymer 1.0)

Tags: javascript, onclick, polymer

I want to change the text of a paper-button from "**Modify**" to "**Save**".

How can I achieve this with JavaScript?

**My Button**

```
<paper-button id="msbutton" onclick="_changeText">Modify</paper-button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Polymer({
    is: "test-button",
    _changeText: function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('msbutton');
    //What comes here?
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the `#msbutton` inside your `test-button` element?

You should use [Polymer's event binding syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners) (`on-click` not `onclick`):

```js
Polymer({
  is: "test-button",
  _changeText: function() {
    var button = this.$.msbutton;
    button.textContent = 'new text';
  }
});
```

```html
<base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<test-button></test-button>

<dom-module id="test-button">
  <template>
    <paper-button id="msbutton" on-click="_changeText">Modify</paper-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: @Vinod Louis   Ya the"onclick" was the problem. It works now. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use via polymer dom selector via

this.$$("#msbutton").innerText = "Save";

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it right (sorry I'm a beginner) but I changed my function to   

          _changeText: function() {
              this.$$("#msbutton").innerText = "Save";
            }

Now I get the Error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: _changeText is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick**

Am I doing something wrong with the reference to the function?

Comment: in html set as  on-tap="_changeText" an let me know if worked or not

Comment: Double-Dollar is very slow on performance as it equals to `document.querySelectAll()` and returns the first match. Instead, if you already know the ID of the element, you can just use `this.$.msbutton`.